# Essay Writing Introduction Paragraph

Tags: style, essay, introduction

How do I write an introduction paragraph when it comes to writing a simple essay for those who have no idea what to write about and I don't have a creative mind? Please explain to me step by step.

Comment: You can't write an introductory paragraph until you know what it is you're going to introduce. Me, I always write the introduction last.

Comment: You will probably get a better answer if you clarify what sort of essay you're trying to write. And "no idea what to write about" will really have to be addressed before you can even begin to structure a good essay. Ask yourself what you care about...

Answer (score 3):

There are different kinds of essays - are you looking at an expository essay (an academic essay designed to set forth an argument about a specific idea)? If so, there's really not much creativity required...

Standard format is to start with a hook - something that connects the topic of your essay to the larger world or than shows why readers should be interested in what you have to say.

> eg. The way we treat our forests can be seen as a microcosm of the way
>   we treat our planet.

You then generally give a very concise summary of the way you're going to structure your arguments.

> eg. In the last forty years, our forests have faced increasingly dire
>   threats  from urbanization, disease, and irresponsible logging
>   practices.

(If your arguments are more complex, you will need to take a bit more time to make them clear).

Then you state your thesis (the main point you're trying to make).

> eg. Protection of our forests must be the immediate priority of this
>   administration.

And then you go on with the rest of the essay.

This is a really basic format for an expository essay. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Introduction in an essay is the most difficult part for me. Let me explain some useful tips that would help you to start your paper. Introduce the topic with some indication of its inherent interest or importance, and a clear definition of the boundaries of the subject area. Then you should indicate the structure and/or methodology of the essay, often with the major sections of the essay or its structural principle clearly stated
In the end of introduction (yes, sounds crazy) state the thesis of the essay, preferably in a single, arguably statement with a clear main clause.